# Как обрабатывает множество одновременных запросов серверная часть сайта на php?

Tags: php, сервер, http, запрос, оптимизация-сайтов

Допустим одновременно в одну секунду сразу 1000 пользователей открывают страницу сайта,куда подгружается много данных из бд. Каков в таком случае порядок и принцип обработки множества одновременных запросов?Неужели все запросы обрабатываются поочереди? как сервер выбирает какому пользователю первым отправить ответ, если пользователи обратились к нему одновременно? Прошу дать развёрнутый ответ, а не вбросы в комментариях.

Comment: В общем случае сколько воркеров запущено, столько запросов одновременно и будет обрабатываться. В каком порядке — наверно в порядке получения на сервере (они никогда не придут *абсолютно* одновременно, хотя бы в несколько микросекунд разница обязательно будет)

Comment: А что такое воркер?

Comment: Процесс, занимающийся обработкой запроса (полезной работой). В случае асинхронной работы один воркер мог бы одновременно (точнее, *конкурентно*) обрабатывать десятки и сотни запросов, но, насколько я знаю, php не очень умеет в асинхронщину (намного лучше в этом преуспели nodejs и golang), и типичный синхронный php-воркер будет обрабатывать одновременно один запрос

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Начнём с простого: 1000 пользователей одновременно обращаются к встроенному веб-серверу php. Встроенный сервер очень простой и не умеет распарллелить обработку запросов, поэтому запросы будут выстраиваться в очередь и выполняться по одному. Если обработка занимает существенное время, часть клиентов не дождётся ответа.

Чуть сложнее: в качестве веб-сервера используем nginx. Nginx умеет запускать несколько обработчиков параллельно (это принесёт наибольший профит, если процессор машины, на коорой крутится веб-сервер многоядерный), но и nginx создаст очередь, просто будет разгребать её быстрее, запуская по несколько обработчиков параллельно. Если обработка занимает существенное время, часть клиентов не дождётся ответа.

Ещё немного сложнее: если один сервер не справляется с обработкой всех запросов, то остаётся использовать несколько серверов. Для этого используются балансировщики нагрузки. Вот как это работает. 1000 пользователей открывают страницу и обращаются к балансировщику, балансировщик тоже создаёт очередь (никакого чуда не произошло), но вся работа балансировщика заключается в том, что он отправляет пользователей на веб-серверы (на отдельных машинах), стоящие за ним, по кругу (первый, второй, третий,... снова первый, второй). Работа балансировщика очень простая и он делает её очень быстро, и очень быстро разгребает очередь. Он работает гораздо быстрее, чем отвечают веб-серверы, поэтому в случае если пользователей стало больше, обычно достаточно добавить ещё веб-серверов, на которые он будет разбрасывать запросы. Важно понимать, что и в этом случае, если обработка занимает существенное время, часть клиентов не дождётся ответа. Всегда есть какой-то порог, после которого сайт ляжет, просто он должен быть выше, чем пиковая нагрузка на сайт.

Приблизительно так это работает на уровне веб-серверов. Однако сами веб-серверы обычно код не выполняют, а передают обработку на серверы приложений и ждут ответа от них. Например nginx очень быстр, но он не выполняет php, а передаёт обработку в php-fpm. А php не занимается работой с данными, а обращается за ними к базе данных. Все эти слои параллелятся по похожему принципу.

В конкретной ситуации всё может отличаться. Например браузеры, веб-серверы, приложения на php, базы данных поддерживают кэширование и другие оптимизации, которые позволяют ответить на часть запросов срезав путь.

Comment: Что насчет Apache?

Comment: @DenisLopatin Apache тоже разработан для обработки большого количества запросов одновременно. Я тут пытался объяснить общую идею. Если работу можно распараллелить (на разных ядрах процессора или вообще на разных компьютерах), то очереди не будет. Если такой возможности нет (все ядра или компьютеры уже заняты), то будет очередь. Если запросы поступают быстрее чем разребается очередь, то начнутся отказы в обслуживании.